# Finding todays date without the time

Tags: objective-c, date

I have an app in I need the date of the next day though I have looked around and found nothing on how to do this.

**Edit:**

Found the answer at last. Here is what I did:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startOfToday;
NSDate *tomorrow;
NSTimeInterval interval;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
       startDate:&startOfToday
        interval:&interval
         forDate:now];

tomorrow = [startOfToday dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy"];
tommorowDate = [df stringFromDate:tomorrow];
```

Though this was all thanks to one of the answers

Comment: 1. Get current date 2. Add 1 day. 3. Check year, month, day components?

Comment: I trivially found a solution (linked above) to this, so perhaps you need to learn how to look.

Comment: @middaparka that gives the time as well

Comment: @OllieCole: NSDate will ALWAYS have time components. It represents a moment in time.

Comment: Ho do  get rid of them @vikingosegundo

Comment: so you understand the word ALLWAYS?

Comment: yeh though is there a way to not display them @vikingosegundo

Comment: You could then use an [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to obtain the portions of the date information you want, but that answer will correctly get the "next" date. Incidentally, you clearly need to spend some time taking a look at the Apple docs.

Comment: how would I set the next days date to an nsdateformatter cos if I can make into a string then I can split it and use the splitted date

Comment: Do you really expect to be spoon-fed everything? Read the docs and search around the topic on Google/StackOverflow.

Comment: Hey I am new to c so don't know much @middaparka

Comment: Apple has some fantastic "getting started" docs such as [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html), [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html), etc. You'll be doing yourself a massive favour if you read and understand these first.

Comment: Ok I am past the getting started phase though not that good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startOfToday;
NSDate *tomorrow;
NSTimeInterval interval;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit 
       startDate:&startOfToday 
        interval:&interval // interval will hold the duration of the day. DST-aware.
         forDate:now];

tomorrow = [startOfToday dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
```

`tomorrow` now holds an NSDate object representing 0:00 of the next day in the device's timezone.

NSDate is representing a moment in time. To display it without time portion, use a NSDateFormatter. There are plenty of examples around here.